# Visual Studio 2008 source control for small teams

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control

I work on a small web team where I am the only .NET developer currently using Visual Studio 2008 Professional to build and maintain a few web applications.  I am about to start training another member of our team so we purchased him a copy of Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I've looked into Visual Source Safe, but I'm dubious.  I don't like that is file system based.  Ideally, the system would work with SQL Server 2005 and plug into Visual Studio.   Windows based solutions are the best because of the IT environment of the organization I work for.

What are my options for a source control system?

(Forgive me if the answer exists in another thread.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) has good integration with Visual Studio 2008 through [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) and [Ankh](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

SourceSafe is dangerous. You're right that a filesharing-based SCM is a bad idea, and Microsoft themselves have downplayed it and replaced it with a new SCM that comes with the Team edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: I've just started using Ankh and I can thoroughly recommend it

Comment: I'm just one developer with two graphic designers. I started using Subversion (VisualSVN) last week and today started using CruiseControl.NET. It has been mostly painless to setup on Win08Svr.

Comment: We used Ankh with Visual Studio 2003 and 2005, then switched to Visual SVN when Visual Studio 2008 came out because--at the time--Ankh didn't yet have support for it. Both are very good.

Comment: I use SVN with team city at home and use TFS at work. I agree that SVN/ankh is the ultimate choice for small team. As a pure source code control SVN/ankh is even better than TFS (sometimes TFS is a little slow).

Comment: Please, please avoid TFS. It's corporate bullshit and absolute braindamage coming from MS. They're reinventing things that have been done much much better in CVS already and they're getting it WRONG.

Comment: @Pasi, I really love some features of TFS the integration with source code control, build management, work items, and bug reporting, it's awesome.
Although, like I said, I agree that the source code control only is not his strengh.

Comment: Does Subversion have an education version for a single user? Or is it mainly for teams and defiantly requires a server?

Comment: Subversion is Free software. The "server" can be run on your own workstation if it's just you.

Answer (score 11):

I can't believe nobody has mentioned [SourceGear Vault](http://sourcegear.com/vault/index.html). It stores your code in SQL Server, integrates extremely well into VS, and is an excellent replacement/alternative to Source Safe. Since their single-user license is free, I even use it when coding at home. Plus, it's the company founded/run by [Eric Sink](http://www.ericsink.com/).

Comment: Of the 5 SCMs I've used (TFS, Vault, Subversion, Surround and VSS) Vault was hands down the best.

Answer (score 5):

Has any body given Git any thought? There is a very usable solution for windows called GitExtensions [here](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). It integrates with Visual Studio Professional trough an extra menu and optional toolbar. Unlike Subversion, Git is distributed, which means you can commit locally to your copy of the repository, and afterwards push the changes to the server. The bottom line? Git is FAST! It's storage is also more efficient than subversion, which means your repository takes up less space.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion. Free.  Visual SVN is a great add on, and is fairly inexpensive.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely, as most people says, [Subversion](http://subversion.net) + [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com).

VisualSVN is a fairly cheap addon at $49, subversion is free and very stable. We use that for teams of 10-15 people and it works really well for us. The only con is that it is file-system based.

On the other hand, if you have a very specific need for it not to be on the file system i would NOT recommend Visual Source Safe, on my last job we had a lot of trouble with it and lost precious days of work. If you want to go that way get something like [sourcegear vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/) which is database based. There is also Team Foundation Server from Microsoft but I believe it is really expensive (and heavy) for small teams.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/)
might work for you, it is supposed to integrate well and is relatively cheap at ~$50 per license. I've been considering buying it myself, so far I just use Tortoise SVN as I do relatively little non-Eclipse work right now.

Answer (score 2):

[Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/default.aspx) does satisfy your requirements of working with SQL Server, but is probably overkill for such a small development team.

I would recommend using [Subversion](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (free) for source control along with [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) ($49) for the visual studio integration.  There is also an excellent Subversion client for windows explorer called [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which is awesome.

The nice thing about giving something like Subversion a try is that it is free and very easy to set up.  It will also scale up to a pretty large team.  It is worth a shot before investing effort in MSFTs Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's Team Foundation Server integrates fully into VS2008 and uses SQL Server for its back end.  The downside is that it's a very expensive solution.

Comment: Depends on what you need it for and how many people.  When you consider your development tools are included in the purchase price, it is reasonable.  We were able to outfit our IT department of about 14 people and 30 additional CALs for Team Explorer users for under six figures.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a SVN server? That way, all your developers can use it, and there is a very good free Windows Client for it (TortoiseSVN). You can integrate SVN support with TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio with VisualSVN, which is commercial, but not actually expensive.

Answer (score 1):

We switched over from SourceSafe to tfs recently and have found it to work quite capably.

The only notable exception in features we exercised is file linking.

To keep the costs down, we make sure that we get the Gold Certified Partner status.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), coupled with [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), a plugin (Free!) that integrates Subversion with the Visual Studio IDE.

If you use the svnserve distribution that's free from CollabNet (Windows binaries: [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)), setup is very simple.  Administration is very easy.  And the product works very well.

It is still file-system based, but that isn't really a problem.  Make sure that you back-up regularly, both full dumps and hot-copies (both of which are explained in detail in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Source Safe has a bad rap from it's earlier incarnations.  They came out with a new version in 2005, and it solves many of the problems of earlier versions.  I don't think they've solved the branching problems though.  They have a client/server portion now (well, it's http based) so that solves some of the remote issues.

SVN is probably a better solution, but VSS isn't as bad as it once was.