# What is the best source control product for Visual Studio development?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I work in a Visual Studio/.NET shop which is still using VSS 2005 for source control. We are looking to upgrade to VS Team Foundation Server and use it's source control system, but I'm curious if that's really the best option. The creators of StackOverflow use Subversion but comment that it's a pain to merge code forks back into the main product (discussed in podcast #52). Joel mentioned that Mercurial is used at Fog Creek. Knowing that Joel is something of a software snob and he chose Mercurial over anything from Microsoft, I thought I would pose the quesiton to the StackOverflow audience: which source control product is the best for **Visual Studio** developers?

Comment: I dunno about best.  But Team System is a pretty bad and expensive thing.  I wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: Having come from VSS and SVN, Team Foundation Server is WAY better for handling branching and merging with Visual Studio.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141500/visual-studio-2008-source-control-for-small-teams

Answer (score 18):

We switched from VSS to SVN, using only [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) for a long time. Recently we began using the [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) plugin for VS (unfortunately not free).

I must say, after getting over the initial pain of not having source control integration in VS, I really liked the level of control I had over all my source control operations. I highly recommend this route.

If you go with Subversion and must have source control integration, I highly recommend VisualSVN.

If you want to give SVN a try, you can install the very free (and very easy to setup) [VisaulSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) product and have SVN running in just a few minutes on a Windows server.

Comment: The server is nice, i can't comment on the client as I use TortiseSVN

Answer (score 11):

My recommendation is for [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/). It's close enough to Visual Source(un)Safe to feel "comfortable" with right away, it's rock-solid (built on SQL Server which solves your backup hassles, too), it's very reliable, has great support for branching and merging - all around good stuff.

It's free for teams up to 2 devs and reasonably priced for larger teams - much less $$$ than Team System (also it's only a Source Control, of course - not a whole team dev system). We use it in conjunction with Fogbugz bug and issue tracker and that combo gives up all the bang we need for much less buck.

Highly recommended.

Marc

Comment: I've just started using Vault and I think it is awesome. I previously used Source Safe (horrible). I tried Subversion + Tortoise. Unfortunately, SVN had a steep learning curve, and was fiddly to configure and use (I didn't try VisualSVN - it might have been better). But with Vault, *everything* is good. It is beautifully integrated with VS, and does its job well without getting in the way. Branching and merging are a dream.

I believe a free single user licence is available if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you want to have VS integration but I question the reason for that.

A good source control product has many more features than just VS integration.

You can get subversion to integrate with VS ( [Ankh svn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) and [visualsvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/) ) and I've also used [vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) which is stable and integrated with VS but I use source control for other things other than just vs work.

So I prefer to work with source control out of the product. You should try it.

Comment: VS is heavy. Very heavy. You shouldn't have to fire up a heavy object just to use your source control. Working with VS is nice, but entirely dependent on VS? I say NO.

Comment: You dont have to use VS to integrate with TFS,  they have Power Tools that let you use windows explorer. VS is not that heavy, I can open a solution with 36 projects and build them all and keep the memory under 400MB

Comment: The first two statements have no dependency.  Saying good source control has more features than just VS integration, doesn't preclude the advantages of VS integration.

Answer (score 10):

I've worked with VSS, CVS, SVN, and TFS.

VSS:  Skip it.  I've lost too many changes that literally have just vanished.

CVS:  Great solution.  Has one feature SVN is missing with a visual of the merging.

SVN:  Great solution.  You can get add-ins to integrate if you need them.  I have only one complaint:  merging between branches could be better.  But, the product is bomber and very affordable.

TFS:  Where I was working, they didn't do much with it.  They only used the source control.  I was excited to use it, especially the shelving, but I couldn't merge the changes to a branch.  I would say it's pretty much what VSS should be.  Sometimes MS tries too hard to do things for you that you just have to do for yourself.  Also, the UI isn't intuitive.

So, I'd stick with SVN.  Though, the new open source standard seems to be GIT (can't comment on it though).

Comment: Yes, I hear Git and Mercurial (Hg) are gaining popularity.

Answer (score 5):

The source control is **only** part of VS Team Foundation Server, which is a complete project management system.

I used both SVN and TFS, and both of them are more stable, robust than VSS.

Answer (score 5):

Coming from VSS *any* system would be an improvement;-)

[Perforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce) is probably the best mainstream tool I have used. Rational Apex was even better, but unless you're writing Ada that information is of no use to you.

[ClearCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearCase) is pretty powerful, but I found it pretty hard to use (admittedly I only used it for a couple of weeks, so I possibly didn't give it a fair trial).

For the cost (free) SVN is excellent. The Tortoise shell add-in makes it very easy to use in Windows.

EDIT.

I see I just got an upvote from this ancient answer :-) This caused me to revisit and I find I need to update my answer.

I now use TFS at work and I really like it, it's a big beast and not appropriate for home projects perhaps, but it's a commercial tool and worth a look if you really value VS integration. I'm sure Perforce and Clear Case are still great products too, but I am out of touch with those now.

For smaller projects or personal work at home I now use Git. I don't particularly care about VS integration though, I just use it from the command line, but at home I switch between several different environments so VS integration is not a priority.

Comment: Maybe another edit on the way? Haha. Appreciate the updated answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had much luck with Ankhsvn. I'm able to use it interchangeably with TortoiseSVN and it does a great job of tightly integrating itself with Visual Studio and the project layout.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 3):

We use [plasticscm](http://www.plasticscm.com/screenshots/gui27/visualstudio/int-vs03.jpg) at work, it's less known, but very well integrated into VS, you have all the options and graphs inside vs itself.

Answer (score 2):

SVN is better and faster than VSS. We switched from VSS to SVN 2 years ago because VSS was on servers in New York and the operations on VSS seemed too slow for developers in India. SVN is faster because it was meant for WAN as opposed to VSS which is for LAN. [Refer this link](http://subversionee.blogspot.com/2007/08/get-wan-out-of-way.html)

You can use windows explorer to perform SVN operations or you can use AnkhSVN to be able to perform SVN operations from VS.Net IDE.

You can prefer locking files before editing if you find merging them later to be a hazzle. But IMHO merging is really not tht painful, because you get to see the clear distinction between your and your collegues code before you go ahead with the merge.

Advantages of SVN can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690766/vss-or-svn-for-a-net-project) on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to forget about VS integration.

Many of the best source control tools have great command line interfaces. I've been happily using Git for VS projects for almost a year. The downside is that Git requires a bash shell and it is not very Windows friendly. I'm willing to pay the 'cost' of not having VS integration in order to get all the advanced features that make life really easier.

I would suggest giving [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/) a try.

I have to add that this advice is more suited for a personal choice of source control. If you are looking for a source control standard for a big company with lots of developers, I would go with a more 'standard' choice like Team System, SVN or Vault.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer TFSVC as it is integrated with all the other services in Team Foundation Server. But it depends on what you want to do.  If you want an ALM solution, this is the way to go. I have the ability to set check in policies, integrated builds, and associate with work items. I like the way it does branching and merging. I can have my testers submit bug work items associated with the code in TFSVC. I have traceability to see who is checking in and breaking the builds. I can run reports and get good visibility into the project. Everything works together.

I hope this helps.

John

Comment: We are looking to integrate other things with the source control, like SQL Server, BizTalk, etc. Sounds like you're saying that if the plan is to do integration with the MSFT stack and tools -- which we are -- then this is a no brainer.

Answer (score 1):

We use vault, Its good. But use Team System if you can b/c it's from Microsoft. They know how to deal with their own problems/bugs/wayofthinking.

Comment: Yeah, you haven't used TFS is my guess. It's the second buggiest SCM i've used. First was VSS. Both were from MS.

Comment: I'll second that. I can't understand why everyone is praising TFS while it is fundamentally broken for our scenario's. We settled on Git.

Answer (score 1):

My vote is for TFS. VSS is more than a pain. I have used SVN outside of VS and I would have to see it work along with it.

Working with source control out of the product? Sounds like more work than necessary. Just because it integrates with VS doesn't mean you can't use it for other things. If I am in VS I want to stay in there and not have to go over to another client application to get my source. I like that VS can check out directly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends are you looking free or commercial version control system.

**Subversion** 
Using [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) you have great, free, open-source [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) plugin which integration Subversion with Visual Studio. Integration is really fantastic!

**Mercurial** 
If you need distributed version control choose [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) with [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) plugin. Mercurial, in contract to the Git, was developed with native Windows support and also Visual Studio integration is much better.

**PlasticSCM** 
The best Visual Studio integration I have ever seen had PlasticSCM which is the simple consequence that PlasticSCM is windows-background version control system. It works really well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe no-one has mentioned Assembla! It's free for unlimited repositories, unlimited users and 1GB of space!

[www.assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com)

Comment: Assembla is SVN, just hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should ask yourself what scm is best for your project.

I like svn cause its free and kind of standard(perhaps a little bit bold to say).

Answer (score 0):

I use both Vault and TFS at work. We used VSS and others had issues with it, so the lead at the time decided to switch to Vault. I have had no issues with Vault, but others had some with merge and branch.

I started using TFS Trial and like it as much as Vault. I do not use many of the extras, such as the bug and work item tracking just yet, but plan to.

Since you did not mention cost and the comapny is already looking at moving to TFS, I would think that will satisfy your need of getting a product better then VSS and allow you to grow into it in the future.

Comment: Cost isn't an issue. We're looking for the *best* solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've used **Visual Source Safe** (2005) and I wouldn't recommend it.  Being a file file based solution leads to the risk of your repository being more easily corrupted.  I've used **Source Off-Site** a SourceGear product that enables remote VSS check-in and checkout over the internet and it worked well, but still had the disadvantage that it was built on top of VSS and the flat file architecture.

SourceGear also make **Vault** which is my preferred solution.  It's a SQL Server based repository so it's not subject to issues with the Windows File System.  Restores and backups can be configured just like any other SQL Server database and you can restore to a point in time, not just to your last backup date.

I've also used **Source Anywhere** (version 2.2) and I found it lacking in features compared to VSS and Vault.  But it was a SQL Server solution, which made the backups more reliable.

I'm interested in trying **Subversion** and if there was a version of Subversion that used SQL Server as the repository I think it would be a reasonable solution.  If you're running on another operating system, Subversion is probably your best choice, but if you're running on Windows Server I would recommend a SQL Server solution.