# how can i share vb.net project with my team members

Tags: vb.net

I have 6 members in my team in my office. Now I am working in a VB.NET project. Anybody can tell me how can I share this project within my team?

I want to have only one project folder in my server. I want all my other members will work from this server's project folder. This is possible in VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ozcecho is right...but, there are **many** options out there.  No need in re-inventing the wheel though, check out a question already on SO discussing source control for small teams:

[Visual Studio 2008 source control for small teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141500/visual-studio-2008-source-control-for-small-teams)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a question of VB.Net. What you need is a source control system. Something like Subversion (svn) or if you must Visual Source Safe.